# Order by Column Outside of Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order by a column that I do not want to use in my `Group By` clause.

So the idea here is to be able to order by this `FileId`.

```
SELECT FileGuid, FileName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by FileId) AS rownum
FROM dbo.FileImport
GROUP BY FileGuid, FileName
ORDER BY rownum
```

Right now I am getting this error:

> Column 'dbo.FileImport.FileId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But if I include that in the group by, I will be getting the record of each file in that associated to that FileGuid, which I don't want to happen. Thanks in advance on any input on how I can get this working.

Comment: You need to use some sort of aggregation to get the `FileId`. Either `MAX` or `MIN` or something and then you can do what you are trying to do. The error is because it doesn't know what to do with multiple values of `FileId` possible for a single row of `FileGuid, FileName`

Comment: Yup this is what I was looking for like Gordon provided in his explanation.  Thank you for the details on why the error was occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide *which* `fileid` you care about.  Then you can use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT FileGuid, FileName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by MIN(FileId)) AS rownum
FROM dbo.FileImport
GROUP BY FileGuid, FileName
ORDER BY rownum;
```

Comment: Ahhh right this is what I was looking for.  So we chose MIN here because each groups minumum FileId would put it in the correct order for when the next group starts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT FileGuid, FileName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by FileGuid, FileName
Order by FileId) AS rownum
FROM dbo.FileImport) X
WHERE rownum = <<your condition>>
ORDER BY X.FileGuid,X.FileName,X.rownum
```

With this any type of filter can be applied on rownum by adding outer where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL statement.

```
Select *
From 
(
  SELECT T.FileGuid, T.FileName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by T.FileId) AS rownum 
  from (
     SELECT FileGuid, FileName, Max(FileID) As FileID
     FROM dbo.FileImport
     GROUP BY FileGuid, FileName
  )T
)Temp
order by Temp.rownum
```

Let me know if question!